# Need help showing that $0.1\ge \sum_{n=n_r}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85) \implies 0.9 \le \sum_{n=0}^{n_r-1}P(n; \mu=0.85)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, probability-distributions, summation, poisson-distribution

I have the following 'homework style' question which I will quote word for word:

> A test is done to check for a predicted atomic spectral line by counting the number of
>   photons emitted from a sample in a narrow frequency range. The hypothesis under
>   test is that no such spectral line exists. Due to background light, the detector will
>   also see other photons and the average number of these background photons is known
>   to be $0.85$. What is the lowest number of observed photons in the experiment that
>   would rule out the hypothesis at the $10$% $\color{red}{\text{confidence}}$ level?

Marked in red: I am almost certain that the word 'confidence' should be 'significance'.

---

In the answer, it states that:

> The existence of the spectral line can only cause the number of photons to be larger, so the rejection region is at large numbers of photons. For a $10$% significance level, then the rejection region is $n_r$ and above, where $$\fbox{$\color{blue}{0.1\ge \sum_{n=n_r}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85) \implies 0.9 \le \sum_{n=0}^{n_r-1}P(n; \mu=0.85)}$}\tag{A}$$

---

The $P$ here denotes the Poisson distribution and my question is regarding how the LHS of ($\mathrm{A}$) was transformed to the RHS:

So starting from the LHS (which I understand):

$$0.1\ge \sum_{n=n_r}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)$$ and subtracting $1$ from both sides means that $$0.1-1\ge \sum_{n=n_r}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)-1$$

Now, since by definition $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)\equiv 1$$ I can write
$$-0.9\ge \sum_{n=n_r}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)$$

Multiplying both sides by $-1$ flips the inequality sign, so

$$0.9\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)-\sum_{n=n_r}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)$$

But this is not the same as the RHS of ($\mathrm{A}$):

$$0.9 \le \sum_{n=0}^{n_r-1}P(n; \mu=0.85)\tag{B}$$

unless there is a way to manipulate the upper index of ($\mathrm{B}$) such that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)-\sum_{n=n_r}^{\infty}P(n; \mu=0.85)=\sum_{n=0}^{n_r-1}P(n; \mu=0.85)\tag{C}$$
assuming I haven't made a mistake so far.

---

Could someone please help me show how to reach the RHS of ($\mathrm{A}$), or, show that ($\mathrm{C}$) is true? Any hints or tips are most appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: "But this is not the same as the RHS of (A):" *It is*. For a convergent series, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^m a_n + \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n$ (for every $m$).

Comment: @Clement Thanks for your reply, I understand exactly how the equation you gave in your comment holds. But, how does this relate to eqn ($\mathrm{C}$)? More specifically, I would like to know why the upper index on the RHS of ($\mathrm{C}$) is $n_r - 1$.

Comment: Take $m=n_r$? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Clement C. Okay then, doing what you said: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^{n_r} a_n + \sum_{n=n_r+1}^\infty a_n$. But how does this help show that ($\mathrm{C}$) is true? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: My bad, take $m=n_r-1$.  This gives (C), after rearranging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = P( n ; \mu = 0.85)$.

Then, for any $m\geq 0$, as the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^m a_n + \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n \tag{1}
$$
Rearranging, this is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n - \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n  = \sum_{n=0}^m a_n \tag{2}
$$
Taking $m = n_r-1$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n - \sum_{n=n_r}^\infty a_n  = \sum_{n=0}^{n_r-1} a_n \tag{3}
$$
This is (C).